# Regex To .Replace Alpha & -

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a complete brain fart, cant of the life of me remember the `regex` to use to `replace` 'alpha' and '-' from a `string` which is displayed in the format below

```
test1-000100010001
```

I want to replace (remove) the following characters 'test-'

I have a work around (which works) but i'm sure i can do it all in one line so less code

```
var alphaRemoved = telNumberSelected.replace(/[A-Z, a-z]/g, '');
strippedTelNo = alphaRemoved.replace('-', '');
```

Comment: do you want to replace `test1-` or `test-`?

Comment: Does the trailing bit always consist of `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: What about `00001-test-1010012`?

Comment: @yunzen looking at the similar question from the OP 2 hours ago, I don't believe that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.replace(/[a-z-]+/ig, '')`

```js
console.log("test1-000100010001".replace(/[a-z-]+/ig, ''))
```

Comment: Note that this is leaving the `1` from `test1` behind. Given your previous question about removing `test1-` this seems different to your goal

Comment: The `, ` in this regex isn't a separator, it means it will remove space and comma characters from the input. You probably mean `/[A-Za-z]|-/`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't understand your note, the op want to remove alpha and "-". So it's normal to leaving the `1` from `test1` no ?

Comment: @R3tep That's right - I'm not questioning your answer at all. However the OP has raised a couple of previous questions about this subject this morning where they wanted to remove `test1-` from the string. I just wanted to confirm they'd got the info in the question right, as it seems at odds with what they previously stated - especially when I'd given them working code to remove `test1-` as well

Comment: Also don't forget we can see the edit history of answers :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeh i know. The acutal `JSON` returned data will be  4 alpha characters followed by a '-' then the contact number.  Mine was so i could see the difference in my table that's all

Comment: So the `1` in `test1` is just a typo? In which case you should edit the question as it's small details like that which can affect the quality of the answers you get

Comment: Why do you separate the dash? A simpler regex  is `/[a-z-]+/i`

Comment: @Toto I tried your regex, but the dash is not removed from the string.

Comment: @R3tep: Keep the `g` flag. `/[a-z-]+/ig`